# Node js Post request ,errror 404

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, mysql-workbench

At the start i have to hit one post request after that all remaining  post request work but before that it shows Cannot POST /upload

I am expecting from the begining after user login ,all post request should work fine.

*this work fine all time

```
var createError = require('http-errors');

var connection  = require('./server'); 
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const secretkey="secretkeysvpcet";
//const auth = require("./middleware/auth");
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:true }));
const upload = require("./uploader");
const{check} = require('express-validator');


var dateTime = require('node-datetime');
const { json } = require('body-parser');
var dt = dateTime.create();
var formatted = dt.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');
var defaultaction="In process";
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(session({
    
    secret :secretkey,
    
    resave :false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie : {
            maxAge:(1000 * 60 * 100)
    }      

}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(flash());
    
//View tables
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));


app.post('/publicationaction',upload.single('upload_proof'),function(req, res) {
     connection.connect(function(error){
        if(error) console.log(error);
    
    var Facultyid = facultyid;
    
     var Papertitle =req.body.Papertitle;
     var Yearofpublication =req.body.Yearofpublication;
     var urldoi =req.body.urldoi;
     var Publicationtype =req.body.Publicationtype;
     var Index =req.body.Index;
     var Googlescholarid =req.body.Googlescholarid;
     var Scopusid =req.body.Scopusid;
     var WebofScienceid =req.body.WebofScienceid;
     var checkbox =req.body.checkbox;
     var webofscience =req.body.WebofScience;
     var quartile =req.body.Quartile;
     
    
     
     
     if(checkbox=='True')
     {
    
     connection.connect(function(err)
     {
      if (err) throw err;
      var sql ="Insert into publication (facultyid,Paper_Title,Year_of_publiucation,URL_DOI,Publication_type,Indexx,Google_scholar_id,Scopus_id,webofscience_id,activitytime,action,webofscience) VALUES ? ";
      var sql2="Insert into log_data (activity,dateandtime) VALUES ('"+Facultyid+" "+" submitted publication "+"','"+formatted+"')";
      var values=[
       [Facultyid,Papertitle,Yearofpublication,urldoi,Publicationtype,Index,Googlescholarid,Scopusid,WebofScienceid,formatted,defaultaction,webofscience+'-'+quartile]
      ]
      
      connection.query(sql,[values],function(err, result){
       if (err) {
        throw err;
        }
       else{
       connection.query(sql2,function(err,result){
        if (err) {throw err;}
        else{
           req.flash('message','Submitted Successfully');
           res.redirect('/Publication');
        }

       });
       
       
       }
       
       
       
      });
     }) ;
    }
    else{
        req.flash('message','Please Update the MIS');
        res.redirect('/Publication');
    }
   
   });
```

*to get started with /upload i have to first submit the publication then it works.

```
app.post('/upload',upload.single('upload_proof'),function(req, res) 
{
    
    var Facultyid = facultyid;
    // var Facultyname =req.body.Facultyname;
     var title =req.body.title;
     var Url =req.body.url;
     var date =req.body.date;
     var Status =req.body.Status;
     try{if(!req.file.path == 0)     {
        var path = req.file.path;
        }
         }
         catch(e){
           var path = "No Data";
         }
     var checkbox =req.body.checkbox;
     
     if(checkbox=='True')
     {
    
     connection.connect(function(err)
     {
      if (err) throw err;
      var sql ="Insert into copyrights (facultyid,Title,Url,date,status,path,activitytime,action) VALUES ? ;Insert into log_data (activity,dateandtime) VALUES ('"+Facultyid+" "+ "submitted copyrights"+"','"+formatted+"');";
   
      var values=[
       [Facultyid,title,Url,date,Status,path,formatted,defaultaction]
      ]
   
      connection.query(sql,[values],function(err, result)
      {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
            }
           else{
           req.flash('message','Submitted Successfully');
           res.redirect('/Copyrights');
           }
       
      });
     }) ;
     }
     else{
        req.flash('message','Please Update the MIS');
        res.redirect('/Copyrights');
    }

     
   
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it would really help if you showed the error message aswell, based on the code alone it's hard to guess what the problem is. one thing that comes to mind is that you're trying to connect to the db twice. since you already declared the connection in the first code snippet, I think this should solve your issue. hope this helps.

```
`app.post('/publicationaction',upload.single('upload_proof'),function(req, res) {
    var Facultyid = facultyid;
    var Papertitle =req.body.Papertitle;
    var Yearofpublication =req.body.Yearofpublication;
    var urldoi =req.body.urldoi;
    var Publicationtype =req.body.Publicationtype;
    var Index =req.body.Index;
    var Googlescholarid =req.body.Googlescholarid;
    var Scopusid =req.body.Scopusid;
    var WebofScienceid =req.body.WebofScienceid;
    var checkbox =req.body.checkbox;
    var webofscience =req.body.WebofScience;
    var quartile =req.body.Quartile;

    if(checkbox=='True') {
        var sql ="Insert into publication (facultyid,Paper_Title,Year_of_publiucation,URL_DOI,Publication_type,Indexx,Google_scholar_id,Scopus_id,webofscience_id,activitytime,action,webofscience) VALUES ? ";
        var sql2="Insert into log_data (activity,dateandtime) VALUES ('"+Facultyid+" "+" submitted publication "+"','"+formatted+"')";
        var values=[
            [Facultyid,Papertitle,Yearofpublication,urldoi,Publicationtype,Index,Googlescholarid,Scopusid,WebofScienceid,formatted,defaultaction,webofscience+'-'+quartile]
        ]

        connection.query(sql,[values],function(err, result){
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            else {
                connection.query(sql2,function(err,result){
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                    else {
                        req.flash('message','Submitted Successfully');
                        res.redirect('/Publication');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        req.flash('message','Please Update the MIS');
        res.redirect('/Publication');
    }
});`
```